# If the circles $x^2+y^2........$

Tags: circles

If the circles $x^2+y^2+2ax+c^2=0$ and $x^2+y^2+2by+c^2=0$ touch externally, prove that $\frac {1}{a^2} +\frac {1}{b^2}=\frac {1}{c^2}$.
[image]

My Attempt

Here

$$x^2+y^2+2ax+c^2=0$$
$$x^2+2.x.a+a^2-a^2+y^2+c^2=0$$
$$(x+a)^2=a^2-c^2-y^2$$

Then what should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

Centres: $A(-a,0)$ and $B(0,-b)$

Radii: $r_{1}=\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$, $r_{2}=\sqrt{b^2-c^2}$

Let $O=(0,0)$, then $OA \perp OB$.

By Pythagoras' Theorem:

\begin{align*}
  OA^2+OB^2 &= AB^2 \\
  a^2+b^2 &= (r_{1}+r_{2})^{2} \\
  a^2+b^2 &= a^2+b^2-2c^2+2\sqrt{(a^2-c^2)(b^2-c^2)} \\
  c^4 &= (a^2-c^2)(b^2-c^2) \\
  (a^2+b^2)c^2 &= a^2 b^2 \\
  \frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} &= \frac{1}{c^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: how do you get the centres as (a,0) and (0,b)?

Comment: Sorry $(-a,0)$ and $(0,-b)$ instead.  $C_{1}: (x+a)^2+y^2=a^2-c^2$ and $C_{2}: x^2+(y+b)^2=b^2-c^2$

Comment: $x^2+y^2+2ax+c^2=0$ iff $(x+a)^2+(y-0)^2=a^2-c^2$.  That is the equation of circle centered at (-a,0) with radius root (a^2 - x^2).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
x^{2} + y^{2} + 2ax + c^{2} & = 0\tag{1}
\\[3mm]
x^{2} + y^{2} + 2by + c^{2} & = 0\tag{2}
\end{align}
By substracting both members of $\pars{1}\ \mbox{and}\ \pars{2}$ we conclude
$\ds{y = {a \over b}\,x}$. Replacing, for example, in $\pars{1}$:
$$
\pars{b^{2} + a^{2}}x^{2}  + 2abx + c^{2} = 0
$$
This is a second degree equation for $x$. Since there is just one intersection:
$$
0 = \pars{2ab}^{2} - 4\pars{b^{2} + a^{2}}\pars{c^{2}}
$$
Dividing by $\ds{4a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}}$:
$$
\color{#f00}{0 = {1 \over c^{2}} - {1 \over a^{2}} - {1 \over b^{2}}}
$$